# Same composer.json, same composer.lock but different result

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm working on a project hosted on a private github. I'm cloning the repo and run `composer install`

I'm getting

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v2.7.38 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.7.38].
    - don't install symfony/var-dumper v3.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.38
    - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v3.3.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v3.3.6].
```

I'm not sure I understand what it means.

Here my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "…",
    "license": "…",
    "type": "…",
    "description": "…",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",

        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "~1.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.0@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.2",

        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "~1.1",

        "richsage/rms-push-notifications-bundle": "dev-master",

        "components/jquery": "2.1.1",
        "ckeditor/ckeditor": "4.4.5",

        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.3.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle-services": "0.5.*",
        "mixpanel/mixpanel-php" : "2.*",
        "league/csv": "7.2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^1.7",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
        "appventus/alertify-bundle":"dev-master",
        "dzunke/slack-bundle": "1.4.0",
        "algolia/algolia-search-bundle": "~1.0",
        "userscape/customerio": "^1.0",
        "dubture/customerio-bundle": "^0.0.1",
        "minube/amplitude-php": "dev-master",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^3.11",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "^2.5",
        "sentry/sentry-symfony": "^0.3.0",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "abraham/twitteroauth": "^0.7.1",
        "gos/web-socket-bundle": "dev-master",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "~2.11",
        "liip/url-auto-converter-bundle": "dev-master",
        "dizda/onesignal-api-bundle": "^0.1.5",
        "slot/mandrill-bundle": "1.0.10"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*@stable",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "3.3.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
        "deployer/deployer": "^5.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

One of my coworker is doing the exact same thing and it's working. I would be really glad to get some explanations about the composer error that I don't understand at all.

Comment: i suggest you to compare the version of your composer with "-v" flag, if you have different version result can difffer quite a lot. Other than that you can always delete vendor/composer.lock and try if changes something.

Comment: @kawashita86 I was using the latest version and my coworker the 1.6.5. It solved the problem. I didn't know it was that different. How could I accept your comment as an answer?

Comment: i've put the comment as an answer so you can accept it. Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often issues that arise while comparing the run of a composer command, can be generated by the usage of different version.
As a lot of changes are made on each release (for example different glob sorting order, that gives different filepaths as well as slightly different regex to match version of the packages),
the best option is to compare your version to the one your peer is using by running a `composer -v` on your [shell](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md) (check the link for more in depth examples and info), and as always i suggest to keep everyone aligned on the latest version by running a `composer self-update` if there aren't strict requirement that requires a lower version.